# Authentication in google credentials by grpc gets SSL error

Tags: grpc, credentials

It might be a dummy question on security.

I'm working on a file access service, trying to do authentication for it.
For example, I should be able to know who's the request issuer, and whether he/she has the permission to access the file he/she requests.

I'm using grpc to do communication, and grpc seems to natively support a bunch of authentication methods. I tried one of them (https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#using-google-token-based-authentication). The client side code is exactly the same as in the doc. I'm using C++.

But I get the error

```
E0812 19:03:32.173663955 3576491 ssl_transport_security.cc:1509] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
```

I'm wondering what else should I do?

Comment: My hunch is that your error is a consequence of trying to connect insecurely (without TLS) to a a server that requires TLS. Even though you're using Google Credentials to authenticate the caller's identity, gRPC defaults to using TLS to authenticate the server (and optionally the client).

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin Thanks for the reply! I have a concept question, what do you mean by "connect to a server that requires TLS"? Without the additional google credential code at client side, the client-server communication works well. That's why I assume I need to do something else on the server side.